# Create a zipfile directly from numpy array without an intermediary file

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, python-zipfile

I'm writing a lot of binary data from an NumPy array using the `tofile` function.

Since I want to conserve space, I'm wondering if it's possible to write that file already in compressed zip format without having to first write the binary file, then compress it and then delete it.

The relevant part of the code is quite simple. Where energies2DL is 2 dimensional Python list:

```
energiesA = np.array(energies2DL, dtype=np.float32)
energiesA.tofile('ACE_ions_fieldrotation.bin')
```

Comment: Yet another option is to use HDF5 files instead of raw binary.  HDF5 supports compression, and Python, R and IDL can read and write HDF5 files (with the appropriate libraries installed, e.g. h5py for Python).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another option.  Convert the data in the array to a string using the `tostring()` method, and then use the `gzip` library to write the string to a compressed file.

For example,

```
In [8]: foo
Out[8]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])

In [9]: import gzip

In [10]: f = gzip.open('foo.bin.gz', 'wb')

In [11]: f.write(foo.tostring())
Out[11]: 128

In [12]: f.close()
```

Take a look at the file in a terminal:

```
$ wc -c foo.bin.gz
      62 foo.bin.gz
$ gunzip foo.bin.gz
$ wc -c foo.bin
     128 foo.bin
$ hexdump foo.bin
0000000 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0000010 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0000020 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0000030 06 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0000040 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0000050 0a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0b 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0000060 0c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0d 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0000070 0e 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0f 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0000080
```

(It would be nice if we could write

```
f = gzip.open('foo.bin.gz', 'wb')
foo.tofile(f)
f.close()
```

but unfortunately, the numpy `tofile()` method doesn't accept the gzip file object returned by `gzip.open()`.)

Comment: Nice. This seems it could work, but any idea on how do I specify the bytesize for the data? In numpy I can use `np.float32` but by this method I'm not sure on how to constrain it.

Comment: The `tostring()` method should work for any numpy array, so you can convert your array to `np.float32` first.  E.g. `foo.astype(np.float32).tostring()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`np.savez_compressed`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez_compressed.html) to save the array in the compressed NPZ format.  You'll have to used [`np.load`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html) to read the file back into an array.

Example: save `foo` to `foo.npz`

```
In [61]: foo
Out[61]: 
array([[ 0.    ,  0.0625,  0.125 ,  0.1875],
       [ 0.25  ,  0.3125,  0.375 ,  0.4375],
       [ 0.5   ,  0.5625,  0.625 ,  0.6875],
       [ 0.75  ,  0.8125,  0.875 ,  0.9375]])

In [62]: np.savez_compressed("foo.npz", foo=foo)
```

(You can save multiple arrays to the file by giving more arguments.)

Read the data back into an array:

```
In [63]: data = np.load("foo.npz")

In [64]: newfoo = data['foo']

In [65]: newfoo
Out[65]: 
array([[ 0.    ,  0.0625,  0.125 ,  0.1875],
       [ 0.25  ,  0.3125,  0.375 ,  0.4375],
       [ 0.5   ,  0.5625,  0.625 ,  0.6875],
       [ 0.75  ,  0.8125,  0.875 ,  0.9375]])
```

Comment: I've seen this option, but I cannot save the data in anything else than a simple format. The data will be read by other people in different languages (IDL and R at least).