# How to recover a numpy array from npy.gz file

Tags: python, numpy

I've saved a number of numpy objects with the following code:

```
f = gzip.GzipFile('/some/path/file.npy.gz', "w")
np.save(file=f, arr=np.rint(trimmed).astype('int16'))
f.close()
```

And now I have a bunch of npy.gz files, but I can't figure out how to programmatically return them back into python. `np.fromtext` or `np.fromstring` don't seem to work, and wouldn't preserve shape information anyway.

I've tried:

```
gzipfile = gzip.GzipFile('/some/path/file.npy.gz', 'rb')
text = gzipfile.read()
```

And `text` looks like this:

```
b'\x93NUMPY\x01\x00F\x00{\'descr\': \'<i2\', \'fortran_order\': False, \'shape\': (132, 248, 291), } \n0\xf80\xf80...'
```

But what can I do next to get that string back into a numpy object?

Comment: did you try [np.loadtxt()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html), according to the documentation it does the decompression.

Comment: Yes, I did try that as well. Gave the error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: b"\x93NUMPY\x01\x00F\x00{'descr':"

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If it works to `save` to a `gzip` file, it might also work to read from one.  `load` is the counterpart to `save`:

```
In [193]: import gzip
In [194]: f = gzip.GzipFile('file.npy.gz', "w")
In [195]: np.save(f, np.arange(100))
In [196]: f.close()

In [200]: f = gzip.GzipFile('file.npy.gz', "r")
In [201]: np.load(f)
Out[201]: 
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  .... 98, 99])
```

There is also a `savez(compressed)` that saves multiple arrays to a `zip` archive.

Comment: A minor improvement getting rid of the f.close() call: `with gzip.GzipFile('file.npy.gz', "wb") as f: np.save(f, mydata)`. Similarly for loading: `with gzip.GzipFile('file.npy.gz', "rb") as f: mydata = np.load(f)`.

Comment: One more, the default compression level used during saving by `gzip.GzipFile('file.npy.gz', "wb")` is `compresslevel=9`. If you have large files you might consider `gzip.GzipFile('file.npy.gz', "wb", compresslevel=6)`, this performs significantly faster (on a 12MB file I saw 5x the speed), albeit at the cost of creating a slightly larger compressed file.

Answer (score 0):

You've been doing this somehow by your means, but you may use numpy functions instead to save and load objects rather than using other functions.

You can save desired array by using `save()` where array_obj is your array which you wish to save.

```
array_file = open('array.npy', 'wb')
numpy.save(array_file, array_obj)
```

Then, you may retrieve the desired array as following.

```
array_file = open('array.npy', 'rb')
array_obj = numpy.load(array_file)
```

Use accordingly, hope it helps!

Comment: I am aware of this, but needed to compress my files on output. In any case, I have files that took 5 days to compute and are already saved out, so I am mostly worried about working with these files particularly rather using a different save scheme.

Comment: @jstaker7 I think you may take a look at this [Create a zipfile directly from numpy array without an intermediary file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27681108/create-a-zipfile-directly-from-numpy-array-without-an-intermediary-file) . It might help!